# Is there a way to set small comments for the user to see when he/she interacts with a specific controler of my web page in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vba, visual-studio-2012

I'm currently building my first ASP.NET web application and I would like to set comments for the user so he/she knows what to do in specific controllers throughout my app.

(The ASP.NET web app is based on a data entry basis)

(I's making very small labels (Containing Comments that explains) close to X controller viable?) - If it is how do i do it?-> Editing the CSS Properties ?
and if is not... Any Optional way?

--Currently using ASP.NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012

--Sorry for the bad English.

-thanks!!

Comment: Is something like Shepherd what you're looking for? http://github.hubspot.com/shepherd/docs/welcome/

Comment: Users don't access controllers. They just get webpages. Can you more specific about what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to set the placeholder text in any input tag and Title property where accepted.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" placeholder="your name here" Title="this is a small tooltip"/ >
```

I am not sure if I understood your question